# Consultar un Map con ciclos en Java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, map

mediante un HashMap crea una lista del alfabeto. Por ejemplo:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

        for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'M'; ++i)  {            
            String alpha = new String(new char[] {i});   
            System.out.println(alpha);
          }
```

Luego lo que hice fue dividir el alfabeto en dos partes: la primera llamada ***alpha*** (que empieza de la **A** a la **M**) y ***beta*** (que termina de la **N** a la **Z**). Por lo que es:

```
      for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'M'; ++i)  {
            String alpha = new String(new char[] {i});   
            for (char j = 'N'; j <= 'Z'; ++j)  {
                String beta = new String(new char[] {j});  
                System.out.println(alpha+beta);
           }     
      }
```

EL problema aqui es que de las letras de abecedario que almacena ***alpha*** se repite cada una de ellas 13 veces. Y por ultimo con ***beta*** me repite todo el abecedario que tiene almacenado 13 veces, para que se tengan una idea, esto es la respuesta en consola:

```
AN
AO
AP
AQ
AR
AS
AT
AU
AV
AW
AX
AY
AZ
BN
BO
BP
BQ
BR
BS
BT
BU
BV
BW
BX
BY
BZ
.
.
.
```

Pero yo no quiero que se repita esa cantidad que les he mencionado, solo quiero que se repita una vez, por lo que espero su ayuda y que me puedan explicar este tema. Gracias

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Cual es la pregunta? Según tus bucles eso, exactamente, es lo que tiene que pasar. ¿Qué esperas?

Comment: Hola, es que lo que quiero realmente es que no vuelva a repetirse el bucle 13 veces, solo quiero que se repita una vez.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener? Creo que debieras incluirlo como parte de la pregunta.

Comment: Como te indican en los comentarios, lo que hacen tus bucles es lo que muestra en consola. El problema parece estar en que no has entendido completamente el funcionamiento del bucle `for`. Me atrevo a decir que no te has dado cuenta que tienes tus bucles anidados. Saludos

Comment: haz el for de alpha y cuando termine, FUERA de ese ciclo, que empiece el ciclo de beta luego une las cadenas resultantes en una variable e imprimirla.

Comment: Entiendo que quieres sacar la lista de palabras resultante de unir la primera parte del abecedario a la segunda. Tienes que usar, por ejemplo, 1 único for que inicie las dos variables y las incremente.

Comment: Es imprimir o crear una lista?, por que sino mejor deberías agregarlo en un ArrayList y luego imprimirlo.

Comment: A veces indentar el código correctamente ayuda MUCHO a ver como funciona el código.

Answer (score 2):

Este código te permite obtener resultados únicos:

1er Método

```
String alpha = "", beta = ""; //Guardamos los caracteres
for(char i='A'; i<='M'; i++) //Recorremos 13 caracteres desde la A hasta la M
    alpha += i;

for(char i='N'; i<='Z'; i++) //Recorremos 13 caracteres desde la N hasta la Z
    beta += i;

for(int i=0; i<13; i++) //Imprimimos los caracteres según su posición
    System.out.println(alpha.charAt(i) + "" + beta.charAt(i));
```

2do Método (gracias al aporte de gbianchi)

```
for(char i='A'; i<='M'; i++)
    System.out.println(i + "" + (char)(i+13));
//i + 13 Le añadirá 13 posiciones AN, BO, etc
//(char) te permite recuperar el valor del caracter


Resultado:
AN
BO
CP
DQ
ER
FS
GT
HU
IV
JW
KX
LY
MZ
```

Saludos!

Comment: Solo como comentario, si las dos partes tiene 13 posiciones, y para colmo al char se le pueden sumar caracteres en formas de numero ( (char)i+13 seria la N?) entonces se puede evitar uno de los for.. o los dos e ir imprimiendo todo en una sola pasada.

Comment: Es cierto, se puede evitar un for. Lo añadí para que pueda ser más rápido de entender. Luego ya lo puede ir. Combinando. Lo tendré en cuenta. Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

intenta con esto:

```
char letras ='N';
for (char  k= 'A'; k <= 'M'; ++k) {
    System.out.println(k+""+letras++);
 }
```

salida en consola:
AN
BO
CP
DQ
ER
FS
GT
HU
IV
JW
KX
LY
MZ

Comment: Por favor, explica cómo y por qué tu código funciona y el de OP no. Así tu respuesta será de utilidad para programadores menos experimentados